# In calculating the abelian anomaly, why can't we use $D^\mu D_\mu$ as a regulator? - Weinberg QFT vol 2 p.364

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-anomalies

In calculating the abelian anomaly of gauge theories based on the method by Fujikawa, the square of the Dirac operator, $(D^\mu \gamma_\mu)^2$, is used. Here $D^\mu$ is the gauge covariant derivative.

In Weinberg QFT book vol 2 p.364, the author says that $D^\mu D_\mu$ is NOT chosen because "we need to regulate not only the determinant but also the fermionic propagator $(D^\mu \gamma_\mu)^{-1}$."

I do not quite understand what he means by that. In calculating the abelian anomaly from the transformation of the functional measure, why does the fermionic propagator suddenly appear? There seems no context to support the sentence.

Also, if the propagator matters somehow, why don't we just use the Dirac operator $D^\mu \gamma_\mu$ itself rather than its square as the regulator?

Could anyone please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weinberg is probably referring to the fact that the fermion determinant that appears from Fujikawa's method can be diagrammatically interpreted as summing Feynman diagrams that contain fermion propagators (and the external field insertions). The only way of having the right number of gamma matrices to survive the trace and the limit of the regularization scale going to infinity is by using the slash covariant derivative. Ultimately, the fermion propagator comes into the picture when one thinks of the gamma matrices on their numerator. Explicitly, in four dimensions you need 4 gamma matrices to give a non-zero trace with  $\gamma_{5}$, so you need two insertions of $(D_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu})^2$, giving the well-known anomaly structure $F \wedge F$.